# Why is "hysterical" applied to women but rarely to men?

Tags: adjectives

> [*hysterical*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hysterical?q=hysterical%20) :  affected by or deriving from wildly uncontrolled emotion,
>   *Janet became hysterical and began screaming*.

Why is the adjective *hysterical* usually applied to women and rarely to men?

For what it's worth, Google Books shows 42,700 hits for *hysterical woman* and 2,820 hits for *hysterical man*, but the fact is I rarely hear *hysterical* used in reference to men.

Comment: It's not unheard of. In the movie _Little Shop of Horrors_, Seymour is ranting, and Audrey slaps his face and says "You were hysterical."

Comment: I rarely hear it used at all, other than as "that was really really funny" (that was hysterical).

Comment: It is interesting to note that the word "hysteresis" has nothing to do with the various "uterus words" like "hysterectomy" and "hysterical". It is derived from a different Greek root.

Comment: Why does `vagina` applies mostly to women? This is unfair and politically incorrect in our antipoligamy age.

Comment: @Val: Purely my own opinion, but I rather suspect that in total, *"You stupid c*nt!"* has been said by and to men more often than by *or* to women.

Answer (score 59):

Because men can't have [hysterectomies](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hysterectomy?s=t). The words "hysterical" and "hysterectomy" share the same root in the word for "uterus". In Victorian times, the root of female issues was theorized to be a non-existent medical condition some physicians called "[wandering womb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Female_hysteria)". This now-debunked belief is widely regarded as a form of medical quackery, but on the upside, it led to the [invention of the vibrator](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1435513/), which was regarded as a cure for hysteria, especially when wielded by the skilled hands of an expert physician. Because those skilled hands got mighty tired after a half-day of administering treatments to patients, and they needed a break.

Yes, this really happened.

Comment: Linda, I would suggest this answer is good as far as it goes. For clarity (and I'm especially thinking of those who might not see the irony embedded in your answer), I might suggest that you expand it. Yes, I mean into the _what should be obvious but might not be to some_ area of, "but as of course we all know, that theory is hogwash, yet the traces of its influence remain in the preferential usage... etc. etc...." I think you see what I'm getting at. :)

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg "but as of course we all know, that theory is hogwash,..."  Wikipedia in the link posted by LindaBrammer says as much. If there is anyone on ELU who really believes it is a medical condition, Linda's editing will not dissuade them (unfortunately).

Comment: @Mari-LouA Here's how I see it: Lots of our ELL friends might not have the linguistic skills to see past the surface, and could easily misinterpret. Nor will most readers go to the link. And I do believe that people who are merely uninformed or confused can be properly guided in their thinking. You're referring to unrecoverable Neanderthals whose biased attitudes are not amenable to adjustment, and you're right, there are far too many of them, but I never give up trying!!

Comment: I am really unsure what to do now. But I'll edit my answer to make it very clear that there are some ugly historical truths behind this word, and for those reasons, I never actually use it in my spoken English. I find it kind of offensive because of its quack-science connection to the uterus.

Comment: I know medical science was comparatively primitive back then, but I think it's a bit misleading to suggest any significant number of Victorian physicians still believed in the ancient Greeks' ideas about "wandering wombs". Just as not many Victorian *chemists* would have still believed everything was made of various combinations of earth, air, wind, and fire.

Answer (score 33):

As pointed out by @Linda, etymologically speaking, [hysteria](http://etymonline.com/?term=hysterical) is *a neurotic condition peculiar to women and thought to be caused by a dysfunction of the uterus.* But very few people think of the word that way when they use it today.

I think OP massively overstates the case regarding how rarely the word *hysterical* is applied to men. It just so happens *"hysterical **woman**"* is a [cliched, sexist] stereotype. With [he/she was hysterical](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%20was%20hysterical,she%20was%20hysterical&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), or [he's/she's hysterical](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%27s%20hysterical,she%27s%20hysterical&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), for example, the "skew" is closer to 2:1 than OP's 15:1.

---

Note that by far most common usage in recent decades is the even more figurative informal *hysterical = extremely **funny***...

> He was hysterical ([about 26,100 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20was%20hysterical%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22he%20was%20hysterical%22&tbm=bks) in Google Books)
>   She was hysterical ([99,300](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20was%20hysterical%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22she%20was%20hysterical%22&tbm=bks))
>   **It** was hysterical ([280,000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20was%20hysterical%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1))

Comment: +1 because I automatically assumed that a *hysterical female* is a woman having *hysterics*, which just goes to show how ingrained that stereotype is in our culture. It's been said that women cannot be funny, might be worthwhile investigating how many "hysterical women" are in actual fact comediennes...

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Your [sexist?!] preconceptions are probably exacerbated by the fact that your knowledge of *word meanings* derives more from dictionaries/etymology than is the case for the average native speaker. I bet lots of young people who routinely use *hysterical = very funny* only learnt that meaning by hearing it used in context (they may well not know *any* other words starting with ***hyster-***). But I think most *hysterical women* really would be *women having histrionics* (the "funny" sense is usually applied to *situations*, not *people*).

Comment: I take your point FF, but I feel that your assertion that the funny sense is not often applied to people is "not even wrong" in my experience.

Comment: I'm not so sure that the expression "she/he was hysterical" is not synonymous with "she/he threw a tantrum". I can imagine a frustrated parent describing  their child as such, and I've read stories where men complain of having hysterical wives or girlfriends :).

Comment: @horatio: Your profile doesn't give "age", but I'll hazard a guess that younger speakers might be less likely to use *hysterical = neurotic*. In which case they might be less bothered about the potential for ambiguity in a statement like *"John was hysterical last night"*. But given ***it*** occurs more than twice as often as ***he/she*** combined in my links above, I think "not even wrong" seriously overstates the position.

Comment: For the record, I was born before the moon landings, but my age has nothing to do with it. I think you hint at it in your own example: "john/bob/betty/sue was hysterical" will not show up in your "he/she" sample searches. "(the "funny" sense is usually applied to situations, not people)" is a horrible overstatement at best.

Comment: @horatio: There are 19 instances of ["John was hysterical"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22john+was+hysterical%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and 12 of ["Jane was hysterical"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Jane+was+hysterical%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books. On a quick glance through, I'd say less than half-a-dozen are in the "funny" sense. You'll note that I'm consistently backing up what I say with "evidence" of a sort, even if we both accept Google Books isn't always reliable. You offer nothing except your (possibly, highly localised) opinion.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I agree with FumbleFingers; I'm 25 with English as my first language, and "she was hysterical" naturally translates in my head as "she was hilarious".  The only other words that pop into mind that start with the same phonemes are "history" and the "[Histeria!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histeria!)" cartoon.

Comment: Break down your data for "she was" etc by meaning and context and then do a search for all possible names, and add in a corpus of spoken language and you might have a basis for your assertion. In your defense it was an off-hand parenthetical remark

Comment: @horatio: There's a limit to how much "original research" I'm prepared to put into this! You can agree or disagree, but I maintain that *John is a hysterical guy* isn't particularly common compared to, say, *John is a very funny guy*. You're more likely to hear the "funny" sense in constructions like *John was hysterical **last night*** (describing John *on a specific occasion*). It's not common to describe someone's *ongoing, consistent characteristic* as "hysterical", only some particular thing they did.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am 24 and a native English speaker. I partly agree with you; 'hysterical' when used with a meaning of 'funny' is often used to describe an occasion. However, my first thought when I hear 'she was hysterical' (so non occasion usage) is that she was 'out of control', 'in a panic', or some other sense of the word in that direction. I think this has to do with how it's used in popular movies. Since most references, that I can think of, to that word in movies relate to the 'crazy woman' connotation.

Comment: @ryan: I don't know what I might have said that you *don't* agree with - I *completely* agree everything you've said there. A *hysterical/neurotic* person is probably somewhat like that all the time, but people are usually only *hysterically funny* at particular times. Apparently there are 1000s of instances of [she is hysterical](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22she+is+hysterical%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22she+is+hysterical%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099) in Google Books. I only checked the first couple of pages, but they're all for *neurotic*, not *funny*.

Comment: I like your answer, that said, you do have a habit of making dogmatic statements. For example: "But **very few people** think of the word that way when they use it today." Well, maybe, that's true for people aged 25 or lower. But as Linda's answer testifies, a lot of people do associate hysteria/losing self-control with hysterical. And I seriously doubt nowadays * hysterical woman* is used as a compliment i.e. she made me laugh. In fact I looked at the link you posted (as you did), four pages, and not one reference was positive.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Obviously most reasonably-educated people are perfectly well aware of the "female-based" etymology. I'm just saying *they don't consciously think of the uterine connection* when they use the word *hysterical*, regardless of whether they mean "neurotic" or "funny". Note that ***neurotic** woman* is over twice as common as *neurotic man*, but etymologically speaking, there's no "sexist" element to *neurosis*. The main reason "hysterical woman" is more common than "hysterical man" (but not so common as OP suggests) is probably just that women are more often "publicly emotional".

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to the "**hysterical meaning funny**" discussion:

The best practical definition of [**hysteria**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hysteria) is "someone that lets fear/any other strong emotion break out-of-control, and **then** starts to look for a cause". The "looks for a cause" part means autosuggestion. An example is that people react irrationally and out of proportions: cry, laugh, etc.

I believe that's the origin of its usage to mean funny, e.g. "John was hysterical last night".  The exaggerated actions of John certainly caused people around him to react by laughing/smiling. There are many movies that make jokes over hysteria (*Airplane!* comes to my mind) exploiting those irrational and exaggerated reactions.

In some cases, hysteria can lead to a ["conversion disorder"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conversion%20disorder) which is also called "conversion hysteria", and is essentially when a person develops physical symptoms based on psychological effects.

As to why it is used mostly in reference to women, see [FumbleFingers'](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/129053/11263) or [LindaBrammer's](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/129048/11263) answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is the origin of [hysterical (adj.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hysterical)

> 1610s, "characteristic of hysteria," from Latin *hystericus* "of the womb," from Greek *hysterikos* "of the womb, suffering in the womb," from *hystera* "womb".

The word *hysteria* originates from the Greek word for uterus, as it was thought this disorder (eg. anxiety, nervousness) could only be found in women.

In Ancient Greece, the womb was regarded as a living creature in a woman's body, which wanders around and causes the disorder. The cure for hysteria was to put the womb back to its correct place by inhaling some good smells.

In the 16th and 17th centuries, people continued believing the disorder was related to the womb, though the reasons changed a little: Hysteria was now believed to be due to retention of fluids in the uterus, sexual deprivation, or still by the tendency of the uterus to wander around the female body causing irritability and suffocation. This is the time the word *hysterical* emerged.

By the Industrial Era, people recognized that hysteria is a psychological condition rather than a physical one, and that men can also be hysterical. The word *hysteria* emerged in 1801 and started to have a general sense of "unhealthy emotion or excitement" by 1839.

In modern time, the word *hysterical* was used against the campaign for women to fight for rights and empowerment.